# Draw a matrix array based in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I need to draw a table in AngularJS based on the following array

```
$scope.list = [
{ "Row":1, "Column": 1, "Value": "11" },
{ "Row":1, "Column": 2, "Value": "12" },
{ "Row":1, "Column": 3, "Value": "13" },
{ "Row":2, "Column": 1, "Value": "21" },
{ "Row":2, "Column": 2, "Value": "22" },
{ "Row":2, "Column": 3, "Value": "23" },
];
```

So I need to get a table with 2 rows and 3 columns
I understand that I have to use two nested ngRepeat but I couldn't make it work

Please could you help me ??
Regards

Comment: group your items by rows first?,

Comment: I'd sugget you pre-processed this array and split it into a 2D array, looking somewhat as: `[['11','12','13'],['21','22','23']]`. This shouldn't be difficult to accomplish with rudimentary JS knowledge.

Comment: The idea is to use my array, because it will have more information to display

Answer (score 2):

I developed the solution I found a filter 'Unique'  [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui-OLDREPO/blob/master/modules/filters/unique/unique.js)
For each unique row number I get the list of columns

```
<table border="2">
   <tr ng-repeat="row in list | unique:'Row'">
       <td>Row: {{row.Row}}</td>
       <td ng-repeat="col in list | filter:{'Row':row.Row}">{{col.Value}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should first transform your array to such one:

```
$scope.table = [
    ["11", "12", "13"],
    ["21", "22", "23"],
];
```

That way, it will be easier to iterate over the values in your view:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in table">
        <td ng-repeat="column in row">
            {{column}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The idea is to use my array, because it will have more infomration